# non-metric multidimensional scaling in R - smacof: why minimum stress model is so different from torgerson model?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, multidimensional-scaling

Trying to understand how nMDS is applied with `smacof` package in R. From `smacof` vignette I understand that one can attempt to search the global minimum when running nMDS by trying several random starting configurations and pick the one with the lowest stress value. Fallowing their example I tried this:

```
library(smacof)

# A) Random starting configurations
# --------------------------------
fitran <- list()
stressvec <- NULL
set.seed(1)
for(i in 1:50) {
  fitran[[i]] <- mds(trading, init = "random", type="ordinal")
  stressvec[i] <- fitran[[i]]$stress
}
min_stress_model <- fitran[[which.min(stressvec)]]

plot(min_stress_model, main = paste0("min_stress_model out of 50 runs; stress=",
                                     min_stress_model$stress))

# B) "torgerson" (classical scaling starting solution)
# --------------------------------
torgerson_model <- mds(trading, type="ordinal")
plot(torgerson_model, main = paste0("torgerson_model; stress=",
                                    torgerson_model$stress))
```

One can see that the clustering is not extremely different in the two plots below, but the differences make me insecure about understanding nMDS. On my dataset I get almost identical stress values from "torgerson model" and the "random-starts-minimum-stress model" (out of 1000 runs) and I expected to get very similar plots (coordinates on the 2 dimensions), but they differ a lot more than in the case of `trading` dataset. Why do I get such differences and which model should I end up using? I'm sure there's something I misunderstand here / do wrong. Any pointing towards the right direction would be helpful.

[image]
[image]

PS: I had asked first on SO, but after getting no answer and only 10 views within 2 days I decide to delete the question and migrate here.

Comment: I'm nor R user and can't speak of the package, but what looks strange is "ordinal" in your torgerson mds. Torgerson MDS is metric, while "ordinal" must reder to a nonmetric MDS.

Comment: Hi @ttnphns, Thanks for your comment. I found [an article](https://goo.gl/Of9bWB) of one of the authors of `smacof` that comes with some [R code](https://goo.gl/KK7DGE) where in "Part III: real-life applications" they use Torgerson initial configuration (IC) together with "ordinal" type (which indeed is non-metric MDS). They also provide the same code example with random starts. So my code should be ok I presume.

Comment: The authors mentioned in discussion part ["MDS can have many local minima with almost the same Stress but with different configurations, allowing different interpretations."](https://goo.gl/MMP7ts)...Should I presume then that is expected to get so different configurations?